# Ui-Grid sorting columnmenu options not shown properly while using ng-if to display the grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using minRowstoShow options for UI-Grid. To work this properly I have to use ng-if on the UI-Grid (Wait until the $http response gets back)..While doing this minRowsToshow option works fine. But while sorting the 'remove sort' option is not shown. I am using externalSorting.. Any idea?

This looks like a part of the following thread.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/1735

Where I get my data using a $http call. Something like this:

```
$http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')  
    .success(function (data) {  
        $scope.gridOptions.minRowsToShow = data.length;  
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;  
        $scope.dataLoaded = true;  
    });
```

And My html:

```
<div ng-if="dataLoaded" id="grid1" ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

This scenario works fine for minRowsToShow option. Since ng-if redraws the grid while loading new data or sorting the sorting state is not persisted. Header column still shows only 'Sort ascending', 'Sort descending' option. There is no option shown to 'remove sort'.

If I remove ng-if on the grid then the sorting works fine. But then minRowsToshow number is not applied/updated.

Comment: Can you provide us with detaisl of what you have done so far? Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance about what you should include in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: Do you have or can you create a demo? plnkr.co for example. Have you tried ng-show instead?